# Google maps API 3: setting elevation by hand?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gps, elevation

Here is a google maps API V3 newbie with a pretty basic question.

Given latitude and longitude, google maps API V3 is able to retrieve the elevation with a service. But most GPS already retrieve elevation, so my app also stores the elevation. Hence I don't want to use the service, but the retrieved GPS info.

To set the latitude and longitude of a new marker, we set it with `new google.maps.LatLng(x,y)`. Which is the command to set also the elevation to plot in "3D"? I mean: is there such a thing?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you creating a "3D" map with the Google Maps API?  If you just need to add an 'elevation' property to a marker, you can simply add it as a new value in the MarkerOptions (how you use that I then don't know...)

Comment: @duncan: 3D maps are only available in Google Earth? So Elevation in GMaps is treated as just one more tag?